# Ignoring if statement

Tags: php, session, redirect, if-statement

I have a facebook login system that seems to work fine, but I want to redirect to the home page if the user is logged in. SO this is the top of my page

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!empty($_SESSION)){
 header("Location: home.php");
}
```

But that gets ignored and it runs the login script as if $_SESSION is empty, even tho I print the Session array on the home page and it always shows it has values, plus the rest of the script assigns session values anyway. Even if I change it to `if (empty($_SESSION))` or add a `else { die()}` after it, it just completely ignores it.

Now if I add anything to print the session either using print_r($_SESSION) or echo'ing a particular value, even if I place this out side of the if statement, it seems to realise that the $_SESSION has a value and does the redirect. I could just put that there permanently as it would never appear...but I would rather figure out why it isn't working now.

Comment: You're missing a paren.  Is that the problem?

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham, it's referenced correctly in the explanation and it should've thrown a parse error if he missed the parenthesis in his code. I'm assuming it was a typo and fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't interrupt the script it will, well, run until the end:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!empty($_SESSION)){
    header("Location: home.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Why is this? whats going on with php? when I learned it,in anyplace said that before the last "if" curly brace must be an "exit;" ... I had a related problem with an null variable that a had to "patch" with "isset".

Comment: @LeonA.G.A. That's not what my answer says or what the question is about. The OP was assuming that `header()` exits the script when it has `"Location: ..."` as first argument; it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `die()` or `exit()` in the `if` block or the rest of the script will continue executing.